how to find $\sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^k \binom{u}{k}\binom{v}{m-k} = ? $
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m  (-1)^k \binom{u}{k} \binom{v}{m-k} \tag{1}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\binom{u}{k}[z^{m-k}](1+z)^{v} \tag{2}\\
&= [z^m](1+z)^v \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k [z^{-k}]\binom{u}{k} \tag{3}\\
&=[z^m](1+z)^v  \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k [z^{-k}][z^k](1+z)^u \tag{4}\\
&=[z^m](1+z)^v \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \tag{5}\\
&=[z^m](1+z)^v = \binom{v}{m} \tag{6}
\end{align}
if m is even. (5) is zero otherwise.
Here $[z^m]$ denotes the coefficent of $z^m$ when $(1+z)^v$ expanded.
however if the steps above right, the result is zero if $m > v$. But in the summed notation there can still be some results.
another way:
$\displaylines{
(1-x)^u (1-x)^v = (1-x)^{u+v} \\
&\Big( \sum_{i =0}^u  (-1)^i x^i \binom{u}{i}\Big)* \Big(\sum_{j =0}^v  (-1)^j x^j \binom{v}{j}\Big) = \sum_{k =0}^{u+v}  (-1)^k x^k \binom{u+v}{k}\\
&\sum_{k =0}^{u+v}  \Big(\sum_{i+j=k} \binom{u}{i} \binom{v}{j}\Big)(-1)^k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{u+v}(-1)^k x^k \binom{u+v}{k}
}$
thus $\Big(\sum_{i+j=k} \binom{u}{i} \binom{v}{j}\Big)(-1)^k = (-1)^k \binom{u+v}{k} $ two different results. where do I do mistakes?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's Is there a closed formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{\alpha}{n-k} \binom{\beta}{k}(-1)^k$? (which is closed as a duplicate of Alternating sign Vandermonde convolution), Vandermonde-like sum and Trying to solve the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{t}(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{t-i}=0 $ for non-negative integers $m,n,t$. There are also several questions for the special ...

(cont.) case where $u=v$, e.g., Compact form of sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{m-k}$.

The is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1-x)^u(1+x)^v.$

There probably isn't a simple closed formula, in general, but if $u\leq v$ this is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1-x^2)^u(1+x)^{v-u},$ which will be slightly easier to compute.
